# do_compare has a result of 1 however .compare return value is 0

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm following http://cluelogic.com/2013/01/uvm-tutorial-for-candy-lovers-do-hooks/
and https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/transaction/methods to implement compare
the only difference is instead of big logical AND (&&) I'm using

```
virtual function bit do_compare ....
  do_compare &= <statement A>;
  do_compare &= <statement B>;

  $display (do_compare); ///< this displays 1
  return do_compare;

endfunction
```

However returned value always comes out to be 0
for e.g. consider sequences

```
temp = m.compare(n);
$display (temp); ///< displays 0
```

I've been trying to debug why temp is always 0 but couldn't figure out. Can anyone point me in right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look in the source code for `compare(...)` I see the following condition for `do_compare(...)` to be called:

```
if(!done) begin
  comparer.compare_map.set(rhs, this);
  __m_uvm_field_automation(rhs, UVM_COMPARE, "");
  dc = do_compare(rhs, comparer);
end
```

Not really sure when they set `done` (one case is when an error is flagged for fields that are automated with the field macros). Are you sure your `do_compare(...)` is being called? Add a `uvm_info in there or set a break point to make sure.

Another idea I saw in a presentation from John Aynsley is to not use the field automation macros if you want to implement your own `do_*` methods. In case you are using them, try setting all fields to `UVM_NOCOMPARE`. This is because the return value of `compare(...)` is computed as `return (comparer.result == 0 && dc == 1);`. This means that even if your `do_compare(...)` returns 1, it may still be the case that one of the automated fields flagged an error (although I would have expected an error message).

Comment: Thanks I'll try adding UVM_NOCOMPARE to every field, don't want to remove field macros in case they are used somewhere else. I'll let you know accordingly

Comment: yes adding UVM_NOCOMPARE to every field worked, I can't use `comparer.compare_field_int ... ` anymore though. Yes my do_compare was working before